# How to create multiple onClick methods in android

Tags: java, android, onclick

I'm trying to make an application that has multiple buttons, and when each button is pressed, it will start a new timer and display the time on the text view assigned to that button. I have successfully made one of the buttons create a working timer, however I'm having trouble making another button do the same thing for a different text view.  I do not know how to create multiple onCLick methods.

EDIT: I'm trying to make wolvesbutton do the same thing as wratihsbutton, but have a separate timer, and display it on a different text view.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.Handler.Callback;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView textView5, textView6, textView7;
    long starttime = 0;
    //this  posts a message to the main thread from our timertask
    //and updates the textfield
   final Handler h = new Handler(new Callback() {

        @Override
        public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
           long millis = System.currentTimeMillis() - starttime;
           int seconds = (int) (millis / 1000);
           int minutes = seconds / 60;
           seconds     = seconds % 60;

           textView5.setText(String.format("%d:%02d", minutes, seconds));
            return false;

        }
    });
   //runs without timer be reposting self
   Handler h2 = new Handler();
   Runnable run = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
           long millis = System.currentTimeMillis() - starttime;
           int seconds = (int) (millis / 1000);
           int minutes = seconds / 60;
           seconds     = seconds % 60;

           textView5.setText(String.format("%d:%02d", minutes, seconds));

           h2.postDelayed(this, 500);

           if(seconds >= 10 || minutes >= 1){
               textView5.setText("Ready");
           }
        }
    };

   //tells handler to send a message
   class firstTask extends TimerTask {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            h.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }
   };

   //tells activity to run on ui thread
   class secondTask extends TimerTask {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                   long millis = System.currentTimeMillis() - starttime;
                   int seconds = (int) (millis / 1000);
                   int minutes = seconds / 60;
                   seconds     = seconds % 60;

                   textView6.setText(String.format("%d:%02d", minutes, seconds));
                }
            });
        }
   };

   class wolvesFirstTask extends TimerTask {

       @Override
       public void run() {
           h.sendEmptyMessage(0);
       }
  };

  //tells activity to run on ui thread
  class wolvesSecondTask extends TimerTask {

       @Override
       public void run() {
           MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

               @Override
               public void run() {
                  long millis = System.currentTimeMillis() - starttime;
                  int seconds = (int) (millis / 1000);
                  int minutes = seconds / 60;
                  seconds     = seconds % 60;

                  textView6.setText(String.format("%d:%02d", minutes, seconds));
               }
           });
       }
  };


   Timer wraiths = new Timer();
   Timer wolves  = new Timer();
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView5 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        textView6 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);


        Button wraithsbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.wraithsb);
        Button wolvesbutton =  (Button)findViewById(R.id.wolvesb);
        wraithsbutton.setText("Start");
        wraithsbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Button wraithsbutton = (Button)v;
                if(wraithsbutton.getText().equals("Stop")){
                    wraiths.cancel();
                    wraiths.purge();
                    h2.removeCallbacks(run);
                    wraithsbutton.setText("Start");
                }else{
                    starttime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    wraiths = new Timer();
                    wraiths.schedule(new firstTask(), 0,500);
                    wraiths.schedule(new secondTask(),  0,500);
                    h2.postDelayed(run, 0);
                    wraithsbutton.setText("Stop");

                }
            }

        });


    }




}
```

Comment: create a child `MyButton` of the Button class and override setOnClickListener there and use that MyButton class there instead of usual Button. guess so.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add implement keyword after the extending the class
and then you have to override the onClick method like this

```
public class Example extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menulayout);

            Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
            button1.setOnClickListener(this);

            Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b2);
            button2.setOnClickListener(this);

            Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b3);
            button3.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId() == R.id.b1)
        {
            //do something here if button1 is clicked
        }
        else if (v.getId() == R.id.b2)
        {
            //do something here if button2 is clicked
        }
        else if (v.getId() == R.id.b3)
        {
            //do something here if button3 is clicked
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

An unrelated suggestion; I'd pull out the time display into a method, as the same code is in 4 places.

```
private void showElapsedTime(long elapsedTime, TextView textView) {
    int seconds = (int) (elapsedTime / 1000);
    int minutes = seconds / 60;
    seconds     = seconds % 60;
    textView.setText(String.format("%d:%02d", minutes, seconds));
}

private void showElapsedTimeOnUiThread(final long elapsedTime, final TextView textView) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            showElapsedTime(elapsedTime, textView);
        }
    });
}
```

Call these methods from the 4 locations.

E.g.

```
Runnable run = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        showElapsedTime(System.currentTimeMillis() - starttime, textView5);
```

and

```
class secondTask extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        showElapsedTimeOnUiThread(System.currentTimeMillis() - starttime, textView6));
    }
```

for example.

Comment: +1 usual steps of refactoring don't wanna have dups in the code :)

Answer (score 0):

basically something like this:

```
public class MyButton extends Button implements View.OnClickListener{
    private TextView tv; /// or ArrayList<TextView> tvs;

        public MyButton(Context context,TextView tv) {
            super(context);
            this.tv = tv;   ///your text views to be set make as many as you want or pass an array of text views if you like List<? extends TextView> as a constructor param
            setOnClickListener(this);

        }

        public void onClick(View view) {
              //run your tasks here 
              //set the textviews as you like -

        }


        public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
            setOnClickListener(this);
        }
    }
```

---

hope it will give you some ideas